# how can i pass an array of parameters to route?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I want to delete some rows from MySQL db using checkboxes from my ejs view to routes with node.js and React app. I can delete one row, but how can i pass and array of parameters?

This is my router delete-func:

```
router.get("/delete/:id", function (request, res, next) {
  var id = request.params.id;
  const sql = `DELETE FROM users WHERE id = "${id}" `;
```

This is "delete button html code" with id for deleting one row from ejs file:

```
<a href="/users/delete/<%=data.id%>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
```

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQnuJ.png)

I can delete one row, but I can't delete more at once.

Comment: Please learn about SQL injection, you shouldn't pass external input into SQL queries unescaped.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use DELETE instead of GET method to delete single row in your router.

You can use POST method to send an array of inputs to the server. So just need put a checkbox for each rows which name is "shouldDelete[]" or another name you like it.

It's important that using the brackets to send an array of inputs to the server.
And then you should use a `<form>` to send your POST request.

Client:

```
<form action="/groupDelete" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shouldDelete[]" value="ROW_ID_HERE" for="row1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shouldDelete[]" value="ROW_ID_HERE" for="row2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shouldDelete[]" value="ROW_ID_HERE" for="row3">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Server:

```
router.post("/groupDelete", function (request, res, next) {
  var groupIds = request.body.shouldDelete;
  const sql = `DELETE FROM users WHERE id IN ("${groupIds.join(',')}") `;
```

Notice: Observe safety precautions when querying the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm getting error when I try to implement the above example when i click my button (GET http://localhost:3001/groupDelete?shouldDelete%5B27%5D=on&shouldDelete%5B28%5D=on&shouldDelete%5B29%5D=on 404 (Not Found))

Comment: @EvgenyPanshin Oh I'm sorry, it's my fault. Please check again

Comment: still have a problem,dont know why if solo-deleting works perfect (POST http://localhost:3001/users/groupDelete 404 (Not Found))

Comment: @EvgenyPanshin If you get a 404 result, then the problem is with your routing. Please check that the path you enter in the url is defined on the server.

Comment: ye,i know,but a i have same url for my solo deleting,and its ok,cant understand where is problem

Comment: @EvgenyPanshin May I see your router?

Comment: @EvgenyPanshin I made a small change in the query, please check it as well

Answer (score 0):

```
      const urlencodedParser = express.urlencoded({ extended: false });   

   router.post("/groupDelete", urlencodedParser, function (request, res, next) {
      var groupIds = request.body.shouldDelete;
      const sql = `DELETE FROM users WHERE id IN (${groupIds.join(",")}) `;
      console.log(sql);
      db.query(sql, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          res.redirect("/users/user-list");
        }
      });
    });


    <form action="/users/groupDelete" method="POST">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="shouldDelete"
        id="34"
        value="34"
        for="row1"
      />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="shouldDelete"
        id="36"
        value="36"
        for="row3"
      />
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Ok, you need to change `router.delete` to `router.post`

Comment: And inputs should be as in the example:
`<input type="checkbox" name="shouldDelete[]" value="27" for="row1" />`

Comment: now its works, needed to be tweaked a bit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).